# Disable an association in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

Is it possible to completely disable the use of a particular model association in `rails_admin`?

I have a model that has thousands of associated objects, and it seems that having them visible/enabled in rails admin is causing the database to choke.

Answer (score 2):

```
config.model 'ParentModel' do
  configure :my_association do
    hide
    # for list view
    filterable false
    searchable false
  end

  # rest of your ParentModel configuration
end
```

That should do it.

Alternatively, if you exclude the associated model (`config.excluded`), association won't show up as well.